# MySQL query to find recent members

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, database-performance

I have two MySQL tables memberships and member_cards. Each membership & member card can have three states.

- Active = start_date <= today <= end_date
- Future = today < start_date
- Expired = end_date < today

Memberships table

```
id--------membership_number--------start_date-------------end_date
1--------**123**--------------------------------09-20-2014-----------09-20-2015
2--------**123**--------------------------------09-20-2015-----------09-20-2016
3--------**123**--------------------------------09-20-2016-----------09-20-2017
4--------**123**--------------------------------09-20-2017-----------09-20-2018
5--------**456**--------------------------------09-20-2013-----------09-20-2014
6--------**456**--------------------------------09-20-2014-----------09-20-2015
```

Membership cards

```
id--------membership_id-------------start_date-------------end_date
1--------**1**--------------------------------09-20-2014-----------05-15-2015
2--------**1**--------------------------------09-20-2014-----------09-20-2015
3--------**2**--------------------------------09-20-2015-----------05-13-2016
4--------**2**--------------------------------09-20-2015-----------09-20-2016
5--------**3**--------------------------------09-20-2016-----------09-21-2016 (past)
6--------**3**--------------------------------09-20-2016-----------05-15-2017
7--------**3**--------------------------------09-20-2016-----------09-20-2017
8--------**4**--------------------------------09-20-2017-----------05-13-2017
9--------**4**--------------------------------09-20-2017-----------09-20-2018
10-------**5**--------------------------------09-20-2013-----------05-13-2014
11-------**5**--------------------------------09-20-2013-----------09-20-2014
12------**6**--------------------------------09-20-2014-----------05-13-2015
13-----**6**--------------------------------09-20-2014-----------09-20-2015
```

I want to retrieve

1. All the active + future memberships + (if there are no active or future memberships for a particular membership number, the last expired record)

The results:

```
id--------membership_number--------start_date-------------end_date
3--------**123**--------------------------------09-20-2016-----------09-20-2017
4--------**123**--------------------------------09-20-2017-----------09-20-2018
6--------**456**--------------------------------09-20-2014-----------09-20-2015
```

2. Active cards + (if the membership has expired, all the cards tied to that membership )

The results:

```
id--------membership_id-------------start_date-------------end_date
6--------**3**--------------------------------09-20-2016-----------05-15-2017
7--------**3**--------------------------------09-20-2016-----------09-20-2017
8--------**4**--------------------------------09-20-2017-----------05-13-2017
9--------**4**--------------------------------09-20-2017-----------09-20-2018
12------**6**--------------------------------09-20-2014-----------05-13-2015
13-----**6**--------------------------------09-20-2014-----------09-20-2015
```

Each table contains about 200k records. I am trying to do the second query (for the member_cards) using a single MySQL query using UNION. Are there any better approaches?

Comment: UNION combines both tables and sorts them, i think UNION ALL is faster since it doesnt sort the combined tables. [source](http://www.iheavy.com/2013/06/13/how-to-optimize-mysql-union-for-high-speed/)

Comment: One query does not return two result sets, so your question is unclear.

Comment: ah, my bad. I meant the second result(for the member cards).

Answer (score 0):

As has been said your question is a bit unclear, but I've written a query that returns your 2'nd target table based on the 1'st one. Inner query returns your 1'st target.

```
select 
 b.id#,
 b.membership_id,
 b.start_date,
 b.end_date
from membership_cards b
full outer join (
       select * from
       (select a.*,
         max(end_date) over (partition by membership_number) max_end_date,
         case when
          end_date>=sysdate --replace with today or whatever
           then 1 --active
           else 0 --inactive
          end index_active
        from memberships a)
       where (end_date<=max_end_date and end_date>=sysdate) or 
              end_date = max_end_date) c
on c.id# = membership_id 
where (c.index_active = 1 and b.end_date >= sysdate) or
       c.index_active = 0
```